# Default argument using curly braces initializer

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, default-arguments

I have this snippet of code which seems to work well:

```
class foo{/* some member variables and functions*/};
void do_somthing(foo x={}){}
int main(){
  do_somthing();
}
```

I used to use `void do_somthing(foo x=foo()){}` to default the `x` argument but I see this way `={}` in some book or online example(can not remember). Is it totally ok to use it? Is there any difference between the two methods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`foo x=foo()` is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization),

> Initializes an object from another object

and `foo()` is [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

> This is the initialization performed when a variable is constructed with an empty initializer.

`foo x={}` is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

> Initializes an aggregate from braced-init-list
>
> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of
>   members and bases (since C++17) or initializer list is completely
>   empty, the remaining members and bases (since C++17) are initialized
>   by their default initializers, if provided in the class definition,
>   and otherwise (since C++14) by empty lists, which performs
>   **value-initialization**.

So the result is the same in this case (both value-initialized).

And the effects of value initialization in this case are:

> if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized

Finally the effects of zero initialization in this case are:

> If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral
>   constant zero explicitly converted to T.
>
> If T is an non-union class type, all base classes and non-static data
>   members are zero-initialized, and all padding is initialized to zero
>   bits. The constructors, if any, are ignored.